# BounceReason field update in the Salesforce on IER object

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, email-template

I want to update the BounceReason field from Marketing Cloud to Salesforce Sales Cloud on Individual Email Result object. Is it possible in anyway to update the Bounce_Reason_C field on the Individual Email Result object from SFMC?

If it is possible then what will be the best way to implement this solution?

Please help me with this.

Thanks
Adam